# Divide groups with PromQL

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I want to calculate the actual Container CPU usage by dividing the number of used cores with the CPU limit (number of assignable cores). Accordingly I get two different metrics for 4 pods:

- Number of used cores for each pod
- Number of available cores for each pod

**My problem:**

I'd like to get the CPU usage for each container (number of used cores / number of available cores).

**What I tried:**

Each of these two queries return exactly what I want:

1. Number of currently used cores for each pod:

(I am using label_replace because one metric uses `pod_name` as metric name and the other uses `pod`)

`label_replace(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod_name=~"rewe-bd-palantir-vernemq.*", container_name="vernemq"}[1m])) by (pod_name), "pod", "$1", "pod_name", "(.*)")`

Response: https://monosnap.com/direct/6EPuLF59HBJaYsAmKG6CM0fRPyUXDk

2. Number of available cores for each pod:

`sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{pod=~"rewe-bd-palantir-vernemq.*", container="vernemq", job="kubernetes-pods"}) by (pod)`

Response: https://monosnap.com/direct/dRBfitwcxHIrTRYDmYHwV5YkomYJjH

This query didn't work (returned no data points):

```
label_replace(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod_name=~"rewe-bd-palantir-vernemq.*", container_name="vernemq"}[1m])) by (pod_name), "pod", "$1", "pod_name", "(.*)") / sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{pod=~"rewe-bd-palantir-vernemq.*", container="vernemq", job="kubernetes-pods"}) by (pod)
```

**My question:**

How could I achieve a query which returns the CPU usage (number of used cores / number of available cores) for each pod?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `on()` function as well. So it would be like this.

```
label_replace(sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod_name=~"rewe-bd-palantir-vernemq.*", container_name="vernemq"}[1m])) by (pod_name), "pod", "$1", "pod_name", "(.*)") / on(pod) sum(kube_pod_container_resource_limits_cpu_cores{pod=~"rewe-bd-palantir-vernemq.*", container="vernemq", job="kubernetes-pods"}) by (pod)
```

Comment: I'm unable to find any documentation on what this `on()` function does. Does anyone have a link?

Comment: @MartijnHeemels https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching-keywords